# Can't install .NET Core 2.0 on Linux Mint 18.1.3

Tags: .net-core, linux-mint

Almost the same as: [Can't install .NET Core on Linux Mint 18.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748176/cant-install-net-core-on-linux-mint-18-1) except that I want to install .NET Core 2.0.

Followed the steps there: [Install .NET Core for Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 16.10 & Linux Mint 17, Linux Mint 18 (64 bit)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x#install-net-core-for-ubuntu-1404-ubuntu-1604-ubuntu-1610--linux-mint-17-linux-mint-18-64-bit)

(no issues on Manjaro)

```
perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~/Desktop/github.io $ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   983  100   983    0     0   2961      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2960

perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~/Desktop/github.io $ sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg

perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~/Desktop/github.io $ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-artful-prod artful main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'

perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~/Desktop/github.io $ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/packages sylvia InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                 
Hit:3 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                         
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                 
Hit:5 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                       
Hit:6 http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/packages sylvia Release                         
Hit:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                          
Hit:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                          
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-artful-prod artful InRelease [2,845 B]
Get:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-artful-prod artful/main amd64 Packages [8,946 B]
Fetched 114 kB in 0s (195 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done

perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~/Desktop/github.io $ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-sdk-2.1.3 : Depends: dotnet-runtime-2.0.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

By the way, the same thing occurs with: `dotnet-sdk-2.1.4` and `dotnet-runtime-2.0.5`

So I tried to dig a bit more:

```
perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~/Desktop/github.io $ sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-2.0.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-runtime-2.0.4 : Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.14+dfsg) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Got the `libgssapi-krb5-2_1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2` myself: 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/amd64/libgssapi-krb5-2/download

But realized that the version is too old... 1.13.2 (i.e. >= 1.14+dfsg)

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install .NET Core on Linux Mint 18.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748176/cant-install-net-core-on-linux-mint-18-1)

Comment: Welcome to stack If something is **same as** another question then its a duplicate and you dont need to create a new question.

Comment: @DaImTo the other post refers to the .NET 1.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad Linux Mint 18.1.3 use Ubuntu 16.04 list not 17.10 or 17.04:

```
perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~ $ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100   983    0     0    830      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   830
perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~ $ sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
[sudo] password for perret: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for perret: 
perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~ $ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Ign:3 http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/packages sylvia InRelease           
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/packages sylvia Release             
Hit:6 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
Hit:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease  
Hit:9 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Hit:10 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Get:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial InRelease [2,845 B]
Hit:12 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease          
Get:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial/main amd64 Packages [23.3 kB]
Fetched 26.1 kB in 1s (18.7 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~ $ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 aspnetcore-store-2.0.3 dotnet-host
  dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.4 dotnet-runtime-2.0.4 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0
  liburcu4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 aspnetcore-store-2.0.3 dotnet-host
  dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.4 dotnet-runtime-2.0.4 dotnet-sdk-2.1.3 liblttng-ust-ctl2
  liblttng-ust0 liburcu4
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 118 MB of archives.
After this operation, 344 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
perret@perret-ThinkPad-E460 ~ $ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 aspnetcore-store-2.0.3 aspnetcore-store-2.0.5
  dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5 dotnet-runtime-2.0.5 liblttng-ust-ctl2
  liblttng-ust0 liburcu4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 aspnetcore-store-2.0.3 aspnetcore-store-2.0.5
  dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5 dotnet-runtime-2.0.5 dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
  liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 liburcu4
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 119 MB of archives.
After this operation, 348 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial/main amd64 aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 amd64 2.0.0-1 [18.1 MB]
Get:2 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 liburcu4 amd64 0.9.1-3 [47.3 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 liblttng-ust-ctl2 amd64 2.7.1-1 [72.2 kB]
Get:4 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 liblttng-ust0 amd64 2.7.1-1 [127 kB]
Get:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial/main amd64 aspnetcore-store-2.0.3 amd64 2.0.3-1 [5,805 kB]
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial/main amd64 aspnetcore-store-2.0.5 amd64 2.0.5-1 [1,162 kB]
Get:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial/main amd64 dotnet-host amd64 2.0.5-1 [33.8 kB]
Get:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial/main amd64 dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5 amd64 2.0.5-1 [135 kB]
Get:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial/main amd64 dotnet-runtime-2.0.5 amd64 2.0.5-1 [18.6 MB]
Get:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial/main amd64 dotnet-sdk-2.1.4 amd64 2.1.4-1 [74.9 MB]
Fetched 119 MB in 51s (2,313 kB/s)                                                                         
Selecting previously unselected package aspnetcore-store-2.0.0.
(Reading database ... 249396 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../aspnetcore-store-2.0.0_2.0.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 (2.0.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aspnetcore-store-2.0.3.
Preparing to unpack .../aspnetcore-store-2.0.3_2.0.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aspnetcore-store-2.0.3 (2.0.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aspnetcore-store-2.0.5.
Preparing to unpack .../aspnetcore-store-2.0.5_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aspnetcore-store-2.0.5 (2.0.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-host.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-host_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-host (2.0.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5 (2.0.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liburcu4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../liburcu4_0.9.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liburcu4:amd64 (0.9.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../liblttng-ust-ctl2_2.7.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64 (2.7.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblttng-ust0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../liblttng-ust0_2.7.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblttng-ust0:amd64 (2.7.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-runtime-2.0.5.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-runtime-2.0.5_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-runtime-2.0.5 (2.0.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-sdk-2.1.4.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-sdk-2.1.4_2.1.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-sdk-2.1.4 (2.1.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Setting up aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 (2.0.0-1) ...
Setting up aspnetcore-store-2.0.3 (2.0.3-1) ...
Setting up aspnetcore-store-2.0.5 (2.0.5-1) ...
Setting up dotnet-host (2.0.5-1) ...
Setting up dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5 (2.0.5-1) ...
Setting up liburcu4:amd64 (0.9.1-3) ...
Setting up liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64 (2.7.1-1) ...
Setting up liblttng-ust0:amd64 (2.7.1-1) ...
Setting up dotnet-runtime-2.0.5 (2.0.5-1) ...
Setting up dotnet-sdk-2.1.4 (2.1.4-1) ...
This software may collect information about you and your use of the software, and send that to Microsoft.
Please visit http://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-eula for more information.
Welcome to .NET Core!
---------------------
Learn more about .NET Core @ https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs. Use dotnet --help to see available commands or go to https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs.

.NET Core Tools Telemetry
--------------
The .NET Core Tools include a telemetry feature that collects usage information. It is important that the .NET Team understands how the tools are being used so that we can improve them.

The data collected is anonymous and will be published in an aggregated form for use by both Microsoft and community engineers under the Creative Commons Attribution License.

The .NET Core Tools telemetry feature is enabled by default. You can opt-out of the telemetry feature by setting an environment variable DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT (for example, 'export' on macOS/Linux, 'set' on Windows) to true (for example, 'true', 1). You can read more about .NET Core tools telemetry at https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry.

Installation Note
--------------
A command will be run during the install process that will improve project restore speed and enable offline access. It will take up to a minute to complete.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
```